# how to save extended-mapi imessage as html

Tags: html, delphi, mapi, imessage

I am using Delphi 10.3 with IMIBO extended MAPI.

1. Is it possible to save IMessage as HTML?
2. If no, is it possible to convert IMessage to MailItem.MAPIObject and use MailItem to save as HTML

This works fine, but takes too long:

```
procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  olMailItem = 0;
var
  Outlook    : OleVariant;
  FNameSpace : OleVariant;
  vMailItem  : variant;
begin


  Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  FNameSpace := Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');
  FNameSpace.Logon;
  vMailItem := FNameSpace.OpenSharedItem('c:\3\aa.msg');

  ShowMessage(vMailItem.Subject);

  //olHTML, olMSG, olRTF, olTemplate, olDoc, olTXT, olVCal, olVCard, olICal, or olMSGUnicode.
  vMailItem.SaveAs('c:\3\aa.html', olHTML);

  VarClear(vMailItem);
  VarClear(FNameSpace);
  VarClear(Outlook);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, but you'd have to build the HTML yourself from all the gory MAPI properties. There is nothing in MAPI that exports a message in anything but MSG format.

Comment: ok. thanks, but if i will convert IMessage to MailItem i will use :
  vMailItem.SaveAs('c:\3\aa.html', olHTML);
so: after loading the message to IMESSAGE, how can i "convert" it to MAILITEM

Comment: the IMIBO extended mapi dose not retrive the HTML body all the time. and it miss the icons in the body and the Images in the body.
i want to create HTML for viewing so it will be duplicate as the original

Comment: If the message is in one of the stores, you can use `Namespace.GetItemFromID` to reopen as `MailItem`. For a standalone MSG file, you can use `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`, but it still creates a shadow copy in one of the stores.

Comment: it is the same with FNameSpace.OpenSharedItem, so this is not enough

Answer (score 1):

1. To retrieve the complete message body with images you need to retrieve the [PR_BODY_HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagbodyhtml-canonical-property) property value which contains the HTML markup. See [Retrieving MAPI Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/retrieving-mapi-properties) for more information on that.

   To get the message body with images you need to search for `<img>` tags in the markup and check their location, i.e. whether any of them are referring to the embedded images. If so, you need to save attached images to the same folder with HTML markup to get the message body displayed correctly, of course, with some modififcations by removing the `CID` prefix from the `<img>` tag.
2. There is no direct cast. Instead, you can use the [PR_ENTRYID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagentryid-canonical-property) property value to retrieve a corresponding item from the OOM by using the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method which returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid). This method is used for ease of transition between MAPI and OLE/Messaging applications and Outlook.

Comment: Hi Eugene,  thanks for your replay, message can be palin text or rtf or html or hltm-rtf compose. so there not all the time PR_BODY_HTML. The message is not loaded from outlook folder. it load up from saved *.msg.  redemption can save with image imbeded. but this methode dont work with Automation. Outlook Message Contain MAILITEM  - this can be save as HTML and do what you suggest with the replacing of the tags with the rights images attach. but it take too much time. to load the *.msg. 
with Extended mapi it's take between 1-2 secend. and good enough for me.

Comment: Mostly Outlook uses HTML based message bodies nowadays. Have you seen RTF based emails these days?

Comment: well, yes why not. and there are some message in the database that are from 10 years ago....

Comment: You can use the [PR_RTF_COMPRESSED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagrtfcompressed-canonical-property) property in that case.